# emacs gnus and macOS mail.app

Tags: osx, gnus, email, imap

I have a very large MAILv5 folder on macOS with 11 IMAP mail accounts over 1 TB of data so I don't want to re-download all but instead I want to use Gnus or other Emacs mail client to read mail without losing apple-ecosystem advantages like inserting mails in to reminder or finding them via Siri etc.. I want to have 2 different email clients to use same database on my hdd. How can I do this?

Note: AFAIK macOS mail.app uses mbox files

Comment: Apple Mail switched from mbox files to a proprietary format over ten years ago. When you upgraded to 10.4 it would automatically "upgrade" your messages without prompting you. http://web.archive.org/web/20070104221822/http://diveintomark.org/archives/2006/06/16/juggling-oranges

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there is no Emacs package presently available that can use the Mail.app database.  The only option will be to have 2 separate databases.  To save space, consider just downloading the headers only (some or all) and sparingly download attachments as needed.

To see write-ups on several mail-related packages for Emacs, see:

[Reading and writing email with emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12927/reading-and-writing-email-with-emacs)

Answer (score 0):

*Copied from my comment on [reddit](https://reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7o37xm/_/ds6ymbe/):*

According to the docs, Dovecot supports the mbox format: https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/mbox So if Mail.app uses that format, you could run Dovecot locally, powered by this MAILv5 folder: https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/mbox

I use mbsync to download my mails to Maildir format and run Dovecot to serve it locally over IMAP. Gnus connects to that IMAP on localhost .

Now I fetch mails manually with mbsync, it would be nice if I could use the power of Mail.app to do this for me (because now I have my accounts configured in 2 places)