# How do I compose an email using Emacs' keybindings?

Tags: email

I'm a little nervous that this question is extremely naïve, but I have been continually (every 10 days or so) seeking its answer for months now.

I want to compose emails, preferably to be sent from my Gmail account, using all of the keybindings in Emacs. I do not care about being able to *send* an email from within Emacs (although I'm not opposed to it) –- I would be happy to be able to write a properly formatted message in Emacs and then copy and paste it into the relevant field of one of Gmail's "New Message" windows. My problem is that, with respect to typesetting, I do not know how to properly format a message for Gmail.

The reason I want to learn how to do this is simple: when I am composing an email, I am editing text, and when I am editing text, Emacs provides my desired macros and keybindings.

Comment: Emacs has a variety of email libraries that can send email using a Gmail account (last I checked, that is).  Your question does not state which of those libraries you have tried, and what were the specific problems with typesetting.  I would suggest choosing a library that can send from a Gmail account and then make a specific question as to that library and what problem specifically you have with it.  See the following link for some libraries that handle Email within Emacs that you may wish to try:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12927/reading-and-writing-email-with-emacs

Comment: It sounds like you want to send something other than plain text(?), in which case I *presume* the alternative is HTML.  Have you tried copying and pasting HTML markup into Gmail?