# configure gnus to read and send emails with thunderbird

Tags: gnus, email

Can we configure gnus to use an external mail retrieval (like thunderbird) to read and send emails?

What I mean is let the external application do the job of connecting to the mail server and use gnus to read and type emails.

Comment: This question sounds more specific to Thunderbird than Emacs, namely, "Can Thunderbird be configured to use an external mail reader/composer?"

Comment: See also [this related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3629/15748).

Comment: Also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38412/read-and-edit-thunderbirds-maildir-with-gnus