# Read and edit Thunderbird's maildir with GNUS

Tags: gnus, email

As forums tell it should be possible to use GNUS for reading `maildir` created by Thunderbird. I did not find, however, any working implementations posted. And in my own experiments I could not make GNUS to list groups (folders in maildir) to subscribe to.

This is what I did:

- Manually set up gmail account in Thunderbird and selected the option `Message Store Type` as `File per message (maildir)`
- Checked Thunderbird's directory where it should store emails in maildir format. In my case it is `/home/username/.thunderbird/some-id.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail.com` which contains the following:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x  4     4k 01-26 10:36 Archive
  drwx------  6     4k 01-26 10:49 [Gmail].sbd
  drwxr-xr-x  4     4k 01-26 10:36 INBOX
  -rw-rw-r--  1 196.7k 01-28 12:28 Archive.msf
  -rw-rw-r--  1   1.1k 01-26 10:30 Drafts.msf
  -rw-rw-r--  1   2.5k 01-26 11:00 [Gmail].msf
  -rw-rw-r--  1 973.4k 01-28 12:22 INBOX.msf
  -rw-r--r--  1     25 01-26 10:30 msgFilterRules.dat
  -rw-rw-r--  1   2.8k 01-27 12:28 Outbox.msf
  -rw-rw-r--  1   1.1k 01-26 10:30 Sent.msf
  -rw-rw-r--  1   1.2k 01-26 10:36 Templates.msf
  -rw-rw-r--  1   2.8k 01-26 10:59 Trash.msf
  ```
- Then I set the following GNUS options:

  ```
  (setq gnus-select-method
       '(nnmaildir ""
           (directory "/home/username/.thunderbird/some-id.default/ImapMail/imap.gmail.com")
           (get-new-mail nil)))
  (setq mail-sources nil)
  (setq gnus-secondary-select-methods nil)
  ```
- `M-x gnus` and press `^` (`gnus-group-enter-server-mode`)
- Select `{nnmaildir:} (opened)` and press `RET`
- ... and see nothing (there are no groups)
- ... also nothing to subscribe to in `*Groups*` buffer when I press `U` (`gnus-group-unsubscribe-group`)
- Tried to change permissions for `imap.gmail.com/` (Thunderbird's maildir directory) with `chmod -R +w+r+x imap.gmail.com/`. Same results.

What is wrong? Why does not GNUS see the groups (mail directories)? How should I set up GNUS to read and edit Thunderbird mails?

(I am on ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Emacs 25.1.1 and Gnus v5.13)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell gnus to turn your Thunderbird account into a new group by running the command `gnus-group-make-doc-group'. Try this:

1. M-x gnus (Return)
2. G f (Return)
3. Enter the full path to your mail box then hit return.