# Can I use Emacs as an external editor of Thunderbird in MS Windows OS?

Tags: microsoft-windows, email

I want to edit the text in Emacs when using Thunderbird.
I've installed the exteditor (https://github.com/exteditor/exteditor/releases)
and specified path to "Emacs.exe" as an editor, but it was not invoked
when I select "tools" -> "edit with external editor (Ctrl-E)" in mail
composition mode of Thunderbird.

I also tried to specify "Emacsclient.exe" with "M-x server-start" on, 
but it was not working, too.

I appreciate if anyone knows what could possibly be a problem on this trouble.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about Windows, but maybe try to verify any assumptions. Can you confirm that Emacs works if you execute the same commands (using the same absolute paths) from a shell? I can confirm that this extension works for me in GNU/Linux (where I point it at a custom shell script in order to run `/path/to/emacsclient -a "" -c "$@"` -- but I would certainly recommend using the default executables to start with).

Comment: Yes, when I invoke it from powershell, "emacs.exe test.txt" get new instance of emacs, and "emacsclient.exe test.txt" opens the new buffer in existing Emacs instance.

Comment: I looked into this a while back. Does the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3629/using-emacs-with-thunderbird-to-compose-and-respond-to-mail/3647#3647) work?

Comment: Nop.  I've read that article, too.  As the external-editor-plugin mentioned there was a bit old, I've installed the updated version mentioned in the above URL.  It seems working on the Linux/Mac, but I haven't found anyone try using it on Windows.