# Editing Thunderbird 78+ messages in Emacs

Tags: email

It used to be possible to use an **external editor**, such as Emacs, to edit **Thunderbird** mail messages, but now I haven't found a way to do it. The [solution to this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3629/using-emacs-with-thunderbird-to-compose-and-respond-to-mail) posted 7 years ago doesn't work on the more modern versions of Thunderbird (I'm running v. 78.13.0). I also tried using the code offered [here](https://github.com/exteditor/exteditor/releases/tag/v2.0.4), but unsuccessfully.

Does anyone knows if there's another solution for editing Thunderbird messages in Emacs or if someone's working on updating previous hacks?

Comment: Perhaps it's time to start using Gnus :)

Comment: I'm working on https://github.com/Frederick888/external-editor-revived

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Emacs Everywhere](https://github.com/tecosaur/emacs-everywhere/) which allows you to enter text into any text field.